# How to escape the '#' comment character within Ansible lineinfile module?

Tags: escaping, yaml, ansible

How can I escape characters in Ansible's lineinfile module?

Here's the line I want to insert on the server:

`EMAIL='hi@demo.com' # Server notification email address enter only 1 address`

But when I try the following, Ansible refuses to parse it due to YAML errors:

`line="EMAIL='{{ email_address }}' # Server notification email address enter only 1 address"`

I'm guessing it's because I have a strange combination of double quotes, single quotes, equal character and pound character.

Comment: not exactly a clean solution, but can you make `'` part of your variable itself? also have you tried escaping single quotes and equal sign?

Comment: How do I escape single quotes and the equals sign? Theoretically ansible doesn't require escaping single quotes inside of double-quotes, but it's certainly worth a try. I'm actually thinking I need to escape the '#' sign, but no idea how to do that. I tried '\#' and Ansible accepted it (that's why I think it was the underlying issue) but then Ansible put the entire '\#' on the server, so obviously it didn't quite work as expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem indeed is the `#` in your string - for whatever reason.

Though you can easily prevent the parsing error by using this trick:

```
line="EMAIL='{{ email_address }}' {{ '#' }} Server notification email address enter only 1 address"
```

Answer (score 2):

For longer form comments or for readability you could also add comments as `vars:`.

```
name: Do something
vars:
  comment: '# Server notification email address enter only 1 address'
lineinfile:
  ...
  line="EMAIL='{{ email_address }}' {{ comment }}"
```